# Use spring tags in html

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Urban Wolf - Boutique Brand Management Firm</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">
    <meta name="description" content="Urban Wolf, the Palm Beach based boutique brand management firm with specializations in brand development, branding, and business consulting. No one wants to be the sheep">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Sheep/img/favicon-client2.png" type="image/png">
    <link rel="icon" href="Sheep/img/favicon-client2.png" type="image/png">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="Sheep/css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p class="form__placehold">Full Name</p> <input class="form__input" name="name" type="text" pattern="^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9\s]+$" required>
    <p class="form__placehold">Email</p> <input class="form__input" type="email" name="_replyto" pattern="/^[\w]{1}[\w-\.]*@[\w-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i" required> <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Send Now</button> </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--end map-block-->
    <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="footer__logo" href="#"> <svg class="icon icon-logo"><use xlink:href="Sheep/img/sprite.svg#icon-logo"></use></svg> </a>
    <p class="footer__copyright"> <span>&copy;</span> 2017 URBAN WOLF MANAGEMENT LLC. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED </p>
    </div>
    </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I connect Spring tags to HTML document, does it really? Or if I work with Spring I must use only JSP pages?

Answer (score 1):

You will have include the spring tags. To include the spring tags, the JSP file should have information the following definition.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

The JSTL tag is strongly encouraged. But to get started on the whole spring tags, you can play with the spring framework sample in the GITHUB repo.,[pet-clinic](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Spring tags / Spring forms, you have to work with jsp document only. You can mix Spring form tags and HTML form tags in a single jsp page if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You must use JSP for this... you can find more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html),
if you don't want to work with JSP you can try with [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Spring tags in html, you must use JSP. If you want page to look more HTML-ish you can use [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html). You can find the differences/advantages of using thymeleaf [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thvsjsp.html).